# Trouble with RFID - reading program

Tags: c#, rfid, motorola, motorola-emdk

I am new to programming RFID - readers. I have Motorola MC9090G1, my task - read RFID - tag and write it down in the list. In Motorola EMDK for .NET is an example of that is my goal. But the problem is that the addition to the list of tags is not instant and a significant delay (15-30sec). How to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main() 
    {
        ReaderForm rf = new ReaderForm();
        rf.DoScale();
        Application.Run(rf);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs before the form is displayed for the first time.
    /// </summary>
    private void ReaderForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Add MainMenu if Pocket PC
        if (Symbol.Win32.PlatformType.IndexOf("PocketPC") != -1)
        {
            this.Menu = new MainMenu();
        }

        // If we can initialize the Reader
        if ( !this.InitReader() )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to initialize RFID!","Error");

            // If not, close this form
            this.Close();

            return;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Application is closing
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Terminate reader
        this.TermReader();

        base.OnClosing(e);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the reader.
    /// </summary>
    private bool InitReader()
    {
        // If reader is already present then fail initialize
        if ( this.MyReader != null )
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            // Create new reader, first available reader will be used.
            this.MyReader = new Symbol.RFID.Reader();

            // Create reader data to read upto 20 tags
            this.MyReaderData = new Symbol.RFID.ReaderData(20);

            // Enable reader
            this.MyReader.Actions.Enable();

            // Attach handler for read notification
            this.MyEventHandler = new EventHandler(MyReader_ReadNotify);
            this.MyReader.ReadNotify += this.MyEventHandler;

            // Attach handler for trigger notification
            this.MyTriggerHandler = new Symbol.RFID.Reader.TriggerEventHandler(MyTrigger_Pressed);
            this.MyReader.TriggerNotify += this.MyTriggerHandler;

            // Attach to activate and deactivate events
            this.Activated += new EventHandler(ReaderForm_Activated);
            this.Deactivate +=new EventHandler(ReaderForm_Deactivate);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stop reading and disable/close reader
    /// </summary>
    private void TermReader()
    {
        // If we have a reader
        if ( this.MyReader != null )
        {
            // Remove read notification handler
            this.MyReader.ReadNotify -= null;

            // Attempt to stop any pending read
            this.StopRead();

            // Disable reader, with wait cursor
            this.MyReader.Actions.Disable();

            // Free it up
            this.MyReader.Dispose();

            // Indicate we no longer have one
            this.MyReader = null;
        }

        // If we have a reader data
        if ( this.MyReaderData != null )
        {
            // Free it up
            this.MyReaderData.Dispose();

            // Indicate we no longer have one
            this.MyReaderData = null;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start a read on the reader
    /// </summary>
    private void StartRead()
    {
        this.StatusLabel.Text = "Reading ...";

        // If the flag is set then start a new TagList
        if (ClearListFlag)
            this.MyReaderData.ClearInventory = true;
        else
            this.MyReaderData.ClearInventory = false;

        // If we have both a reader and a reader data
        if((this.MyReader != null) && (this.MyReaderData != null))
        {
            // Submit a read
            this.MyReader.Actions.Read(this.MyReaderData);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stop all reads on the reader
    /// </summary>
    private void StopRead()
    {
        // If we have a reader
        if ( this.MyReader != null )
        {
            // Prevent new reads
            this.MyReader.TriggerNotify -= this.MyTriggerHandler;

            // Disable the timer
            this.ReaderTimer.Enabled = false;

            // Try to cancel pending read or wait for it's completion
            this.MyReader.Actions.Flush();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handles Stage2 Notification from the trigger
    /// </summary>
    private void MyTrigger_Pressed(object sender, Symbol.RFID.TriggerEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( e.NewState == Symbol.RFID.TriggerState.STAGE2 )
        {
            this.StatusLabel.Text = "Trigger Pressed. Reader Busy...";

            // If another RFID operation has not already started
            if (!this.MyReader.Info.IsBusy)
            {
                // Start a new read
                this.StartRead();
            }

            // Set timer which handles sending further reads until trigger is released
            this.ReaderTimer.Interval = 2000;
            this.ReaderTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
        else if ( e.NewState == Symbol.RFID.TriggerState.RELEASED )
        {
            this.StatusLabel.Text = "Press trigger to read RFID tags";

            // Disable the timer
            this.ReaderTimer.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Submits a new read at every timer tick
    /// </summary>
    private void ReaderTimer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // If another RFID operation has not already started
        if (!this.MyReader.Info.IsBusy)
        {
            // Start a new read
            this.StartRead();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Read complete or failure notification
    /// </summary>
    private void MyReader_ReadNotify(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the next ReaderData
        Symbol.RFID.ReaderData TheReaderData =
            (Symbol.RFID.ReaderData)this.MyReader.GetNextReaderData();

        // If it is a successful read (as opposed to a failed one)
        if ( TheReaderData.Result == Symbol.Results.SUCCESS )
        {
            // Handle the data from this read
            this.HandleData(TheReaderData);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Handle data from the reader
    /// </summary>
    private void HandleData(Symbol.RFID.ReaderData TheReaderData)
    {
        // Clear the previous list
        this.ReaderDataListView.Items.Clear();

        // Populate the list with the updated data
        for (int i=0; i<MyReaderData.TagList.TotalTags; i++)
        {
            string[] sItems = new string[] 
                                {
                                    i.ToString(), 
                                    MyReaderData.TagList[i].ToString(), 
                                    MyReaderData.TagList[i].ReadCount.ToString()
                                };

            this.ReaderDataListView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(sItems));
        }

        // Clear the flag so that the Taglist is maintained
        ClearListFlag = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the Inventory list on the form and sets the flag to
    /// start a new inventory.
    /// </summary>
    private void btnClearList_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Clear the previous list
        this.ReaderDataListView.Items.Clear();

        // Set the flag to notify StartRead to start a new inventory
        ClearListFlag = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Exits the application.
    /// </summary>
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // Close this form
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnClearList_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Checks if the key pressed was an enter button (character code 13)
        if (e.KeyValue == (char)13)
            btnClearList_Click(this, e);
    }

    private void btnExit_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // Checks if the key pressed was an enter button (character code 13)
        if (e.KeyValue == (char)13)
            btnExit_Click(this, e);
    }

    private void ReaderForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ReaderDataListView.Focus();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when ReaderForm is activated
    /// </summary>
    private void ReaderForm_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Enable the trigger
        if (this.MyReader != null)
            this.MyReader.TriggerNotify += this.MyTriggerHandler;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when ReaderForm is deactivated
    /// </summary>
    private void ReaderForm_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Disable the trigger
        if (this.MyReader != null)
            this.MyReader.TriggerNotify -= this.MyTriggerHandler;
    }

    private void ReaderForm_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bInitialScale == true)
        {
            return; // Return if the initial scaling (from scratch)is not complete.
        }

        if (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width > Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height) // If landscape orientation
        {
            if (bPortrait != false) // If an orientation change has occured to landscape
            {
                bPortrait = false; // Set the orientation flag accordingly.
                bInitialScale = true; // An initial scaling is required due to orientation change.
                Scale(this); // Scale the GUI.
            }
            else
            {   // No orientation change has occured
                bSkipMaxLen = true; // Initial scaling is now complete, so skipping the max. length restriction is now possible.
                Scale(this); // Scale the GUI.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Similarly for the portrait orientation...
            if (bPortrait != true)
            {
                bPortrait = true;
                bInitialScale = true;
                Scale(this);
            }
            else
            {
                bSkipMaxLen = true;
                Scale(this);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

Initially thought that the problem in the timer:

```
// Set timer which handles sending further reads until trigger is released
        this.ReaderTimer.Interval = 2000;
        this.ReaderTimer.Enabled = true;
```

However, setting the interval 0 does not solve the problem. And for the start of the reading by pressing the "trigger" until read tags in the list, tags read as 20+ times.

Answer (score 2):

You have to be a little bit more specific on what resources are you currently using and SDK platform you are targeting. In order to be clear most of the EMDKs have a version number and depending on it and on the CF you are using your implementation will have minor or major differences.
But a very simple implementation of an RFID tags reading and listing process will be.

Connect to the reader:

```
        string hostName = "localhost 
        rfidReader = new RFIDReader(hostName, 0, 0);
        try
        {
            rfidReader.Connect();

            AccessComplete = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            rfidReader.Events.NotifyInventoryStartEvent = true;
            rfidReader.Events.NotifyAccessStartEvent = true;
            rfidReader.Events.NotifyAccessStopEvent = true;
            rfidReader.Events.NotifyInventoryStopEvent = true;
            rfidReader.Events.NotifyAntennaEvent = true;
            rfidReader.Events.NotifyBufferFullWarningEvent = true;
            rfidReader.Events.NotifyBufferFullEvent = true;
            rfidReader.Events.NotifyGPIEvent = true;
            rfidReader.Events.NotifyReaderDisconnectEvent = true;
            rfidReader.Events.NotifyReaderExceptionEvent = true;
            rfidReader.Events.AttachTagDataWithReadEvent = false; //true if ReadNotify is ON
            // Regitering for status event notification
            rfidReader.Events.StatusNotify += new Events.StatusNotifyHandler(Events_StatusNotify);

        // Exclude the events each other for best results in my case I use Status Notify only

            //// Registering for read tag event notification
            //rfidReader.Events.ReadNotify += new Events.ReadNotifyHandler(Events_ReadNotify);

        }
        catch (OperationFailureException operationFailureException)
        {
           // Handle this exception type
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle general exception type
        }
```

Then go and execute the Inventory using the Trigger press and release event

```
        #region Postfilters

        // Add postfilters if you need them
        PostFilter posFilter = new PostFilter();
        posFilter.UseRSSIRangeFilter = true;
        posFilter.RssiRangeFilter.MatchRange = MATCH_RANGE.WITHIN_RANGE;
        posFilter.RssiRangeFilter.PeakRSSILowerLimit = lowLimit;
        posFilter.RssiRangeFilter.PeakRSSIUpperLimit = upLimit;

        #endregion

        #region TriggerInfo

        // Control Inventory using Handheld Trigger Events
        TriggerInfo triggerInfo = new TriggerInfo();
        triggerInfo.TagReportTrigger = 0;
        triggerInfo.StartTrigger.Type = START_TRIGGER_TYPE.START_TRIGGER_TYPE_HANDHELD;
        triggerInfo.StartTrigger.Handheld.HandheldEvent = HANDHELD_TRIGGER_EVENT_TYPE.HANDHELD_TRIGGER_PRESSED;
        triggerInfo.StopTrigger.Type = STOP_TRIGGER_TYPE.STOP_TRIGGER_TYPE_HANDHELD_WITH_TIMEOUT;
        triggerInfo.StopTrigger.Handheld.HandheldEvent = HANDHELD_TRIGGER_EVENT_TYPE.HANDHELD_TRIGGER_RELEASED;
        triggerInfo.StopTrigger.Handheld.Timeout = 0;

        #endregion

        //Perform inventory
        rfidReader.Actions.Inventory.Perform(posFilter, triggerInfo, null);
```

Then implement your Status Notify function

```
    private void Events_StatusNotify(object sender, Events.StatusEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.StatusEventData.StatusEventType == Symbol.RFID3.Events.STATUS_EVENT_TYPE.INVENTORY_STOP_EVENT)
        {
            TagData[] inventoryTags = rfidReader.Actions.GetReadTags(5); // set number of tags you want to save
```

Then you have inventoryTags array the Tags you need.

Use TagData properties to list them on your (e.g. the TagID property)

And finally unsubscribe the EventHandler and disconnect your reader properly

```
rfidReader.Events.StatusNotify -= new Events.StatusNotifyHandler(Events_StatusNotify);

rfidReader.Disconnect();
```

And that's it

I hope this may help

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer to example.